# Hold space bar and jump?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

So my problem here is that when the player holds the space button the addForce function is increased which I don't want.

So what I want is that if a player holds the space button they can keep jumping continuously if they're on the ground...

Here is my code:

```
    private void Update()
{
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(1.0f * movementSpeed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);

    if (IsGrounded() && Input.GetKey("Jump")) 
    {

        Debug.Log("IS JUMPING");
        _rigidBody.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);

    }
}
```

This is the IsGrounded Code:

```
    private bool IsGrounded()
{
    RaycastHit2D raycastHid2d = Physics2D.BoxCast(boxCollider2d.bounds.center, boxCollider2d.bounds.size, 0f, Vector2.down, .1f, layerMask);
    //Debug.Log(raycastHid2d.collider);
    return raycastHid2d.collider != null;
}
```

Comment: well what does your `IsGrounded()` do exactly? ... as alternative simply add a little cooldown so the physics has enough time to actually get away from the ground ;)

Comment: @derHugo
I updated my description...

Answer (score 4):

As said the issue is most probably that the rigibody doesn't move far enough away from the ground immediately so you might get multiple input frames before `IsGrounded` returns `false`.

In general for physics related things you should rather use [`FixedUdpate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html).

While `Update` is executed every frame, `FixedUpdate` uses a fixed time delta => There might be multiple `Update` calls before he physics are actually applied and your scene is updated accordingly!

While you will want to get one time event input (`GetKeyDown`) still in `Update` (otherwise you might miss it) I would move continuous user input into `FixedUpdate`

```
[Serializefield] Rigidbody2D rigidbody;

private void Awake()
{
    if(!rigidbody) rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigigbody2D>();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(movementSpeed, rigidbody.velocity.y);

    if (IsGrounded() && Input.GetKey("Jump")) 
    {
        Debug.Log("IS JUMPING");
        rigidbody.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

---

And as said just to be super sure you could still add some cooldown like e.g.

```
private float timer;
public float jumpCooldown = 0.1f;

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(movementSpeed, rigidbody.velocity.y);

    timer += Time.deltaTime;
    if(timer < jumpCooldown) return;

    if (IsGrounded() && Input.GetKey("Jump")) 
    {
        Debug.Log("IS JUMPING");
        rigidbody.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);

        timer = 0f;
    }
}
```